# How to make domain component's property persistent when it has getter and setter?

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I made this domain component. I want to have a property, that return value based on some condition. And I want that property (`TestConditionalReturnValue`) to be saved into database.

```
[DomainComponent]
[NavigationItem("TestDcs")]
public interface TestDc
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    float TestConditionalReturnStoredValue { get; set; }
    [NonPersistentDc] //I added this because else is impossible to run th eproject. Error telling I need to remove getter and setter or make property non persistent.
    float TestConditionalReturnValue { get; set; } //I want this property to be persistent and it's getter and setter active
}

[DomainLogic(typeof(TestDc))]
public class TestDcLogic
{
    public static float Get_TestConditionalReturnValue(TestDc instance, IObjectSpace object_space)
    {
        if (instance.Name == "something")
            return 123;
        else
            return instance.TestConditionalReturnStoredValue;
    }

    public static void Set_TestConditionalReturnValue(TestDc instance, IObjectSpace object_space, float value)
    {
        instance.TestConditionalReturnStoredValue = value;
    }
}
```

In other words, I want this XPO analog:

```
[NavigationItem("TestXpos")]
public class TestXpo : BaseObject
{
    string Name_private;
    public string Name { get { return this.Name_private; } set { SetPropertyValue<string>("Name", ref this.Name_private, value); } }
    float TestConditionalReturnStoredValue; //this property does not have a column in database
    public float TestConditionalReturnValue //this property is saved into database and exactly what I want
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Name == "something")
                return 123;
            else
                return this.TestConditionalReturnStoredValue;
        }

        set { SetPropertyValue<float>("TestConditionalReturnValue", ref this.TestConditionalReturnStoredValue, value); }
    }

    public TestXpo(Session session) : base(session)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it using Entity Framework.

```
[DomainComponent]
[NavigationItem("TestDcs")]
public class MyNPRecord
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }  // we need a unique key somehow
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public float TestValue { get; set; }

    private MyDataRecord _myData;

    [Browsable(false)]
    public virtual MyDataRecord MyData { 
        get => _myData ?? (_myData = new MyDataRecord());
        set => _myData = value; 
    }
}

public class MyDataRecord
{
    [Key] public int Id { get; set; }  // assumedly your table has a key
    public float MyFloat { get; set; }
}
```

In the DbContext class I have

```
public DbSet<MyDataRecord>  MyDataRecords { get; set; }
```

However it needs some code to populate the MyNPRecords otherwise the UI will let you add records but you wont be able to see them next time you run.

[image: Adding a record]